# What's the easiest way to parse the anchor out of the current page's location?

Tags: javascript

I need to the anchor out of a `window.location` in JavaScript, such as the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/page.html#anchor1
```

What's the easiest method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: Dang, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 5):

This should be exactly what you want:

```
window.location.hash
```