# How do I get the value after hash (#) from a URL using jquery and use in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

i have a page that get url address with hash(#):
localhost:15164/L3/mobile/#Android/Alcatel

i want to get url address with jquery and use it on page load event in code behind.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var url = window.location.href;
                var rest = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("#") + 1, url.length);
                $('#urlLable').text(rest); 

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="urlLable" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page load ( to get address from jquery):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            urlLable.DataBind();
            string urlStr = urlLable.Text;
            Response.Write(urlStr);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to parse the anchor out of the current page's location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693844/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-the-anchor-out-of-the-current-pages-location)

Answer (score 0):

The hash is available here:

```
location.hash
```

Comment: Ah sorry. Afaik the hash is not send to the server side. You could only pass it to the server by ajax or put it in a hidden input after page load.

Comment: i send hash to server side by hidden , but not used it on page load event,

Comment: In that code, you only put the hash into an element `#urlLable`, but it's not being sent to the server. You can do that by using `$.ajax` but it will only happen after page load.